# How does watchQuery works with ApolloClient

Tags: graphql-js

I am trying to include polling on fetching data with ApoloClient. query was working fine but watchQuery seems does not work. can someone help me why? here is the code below.

```js
// this was working
let data = await ApolloClient.query({
  query,
  variables: {itemId},
  fetchPolicy: "network-only"
});
```

Now I need to include polling to the fetch data with specified time interval. What I have tried but did not work:

```js
let data = await ApolloClient.watchQuery({
  query,
  variables: {itemId},
  fetchPolicy: "network-only",
  pollInterval: 500
});
```